# Can a device with static native IP communicate with another device getting IP from DHCP

Tags: router, ip

I have a device with a native IP : 192.168.0.1 - 255.255.255.0

I would like to know if it is possible for my computer to join this network using my router set to give ip address from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.10 - 255.255.255.0

I have plugged ethernet cable like this :

- From Device to netgear
- From PC to Netgear
- From Router to Netgear

It's working fine if I set a static ip on my computer.

My question is, if the device has a native ip from a native network set from his own NIC, can I join the network using the router or will the router only allow communication with DHCP ip range ?

Comment: Routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network. On the same network, your packets do not pass through a router, and the router does not affect the communication. The frames are bridged using a switch or WAP and communicate directly from host to host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosts within the same IP network communicate directly with each other. "Directly" meaning they send packets through a switch, or just a direct connection. The sender uses the destination's MAC address (determined by ARP for IPv4 or NDP for IPv6) in the data link layer frame, and the frame is sent end-to-end.

Where the IP addresses are assigned by - statically configured or by DHCP - doesn't matter.